# UNION and ORDER By MySql

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, joomla

I have used below query but it is showing error.

```
SELECT 
    id as number,id,parentid,videoid,subject,name,created,message 
FROM 
    umqlh_hdflv_comments 
WHERE 
    `parentid` = '0' 
    AND `published` = '1' 
    AND `videoid` = '8' 
ORDER BY 
    number DESC,
    parentid 
UNION ( 
    SELECT 
        parentid as number,id,parentid,videoid,subject,name,created,message 
    FROM 
        umqlh_hdflv_comments 
    WHERE 
        `parentid` != '0' 
        AND `published` = '1' 
        AND `videoid` = '8'
    )
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please improve the readability of your SQL by splitting it into multiple lines. It is really hard to take a look.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` at very end of the sql statement.

Comment: You can't use order by like that with a union.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` needs to applied at end of the complete sql statement,

```
SELECT 
    id as number,
    id,
    parentid,
    videoid,
    subject,
    name,
    created,
    message 
FROM 
    umqlh_hdflv_comments 
WHERE 
    `parentid` = '0' 
    AND `published` = '1' 
    AND `videoid` = '8' 
 UNION ( 
    SELECT 
        parentid as number,
        id,
        parentid,
        videoid,
        subject,
        name,
        created,
        message 
    FROM 
        umqlh_hdflv_comments 
    WHERE 
        `parentid` != '0' 
        AND `published` = '1' 
        AND `videoid` = '8'
    )
    ORDER BY number DESC,parentid
```

*[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically you need to move the order by to the end of query. Other than for optimizations such as "limit" it does not make sense to order one of the parts in a union since the result is not guaranteed to be sorted anyhow.

```
SELECT id as number
      ,id
      ,parentid
      ,videoid
      ,subject
      ,name
      ,created,message 
FROM umqlh_hdflv_comments 
WHERE `parentid` = '0' 
  AND `published` = '1' 
  AND `videoid` = '8' 
UNION 
SELECT parentid as number
     ,id
     ,parentid
     ,videoid
     ,subject
     ,name
     ,created,message 
FROM umqlh_hdflv_comments 
WHERE `parentid` != '0' 
 AND `published` = '1' 
 AND `videoid` = '8'
ORDER BY number DESC,parentid
```

However this query could also be expressed as:

```
SELECT case when parentid = 0 then id else parentid end as number
      ,id
      ,parentid
      ,videoid
      ,subject
      ,name
      ,created,message 
FROM umqlh_hdflv_comments 
WHERE `published` = '1' 
  AND `videoid` = '8' 
ORDER BY number DESC,parentid
```

If parentid can be null you need to add parentid is not null to the where clause. Furthermore if rows are not unique (I assumed this since the column is named id), you need to add distinct for the query to be equivalent.